# How to batch add libraries to a lot of projects

Tags: android, eclipse, libraries

I'm studying the Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development and I'm running the projects from his GitHub repository. The thing is: there's like 100 projects at a minimum and every single one of them I have to add manually the ActionBar Sherlock and Google Play Services because the projects usually come with a broken reference to them. Is there a way that I can list all of my projects and just add the libraries to them all at once. This is such a pain and so unproductive.

Answer (score 1):

As noted on [the `cw-omnibus` repository home page](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus):

> These projects can be imported using the normal Eclipse import process. That being said, importing all the projects is probably a **really bad idea**, simply because there are so many of them. Import select projects, if and when you need them.

Beyond that, you are welcome to write yourself a script that fixes up the `project.properties` files to point to your locations of these library projects, for those `project.properties` files that refer to other locations.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to Android Studio; it's the future. With Android Studio, you can set up libraries as project libraries in Module Settings. Then, every module you add to that project can use those libraries.

Comment: You can only open 1 project per window in that. There's a LOAD of options on that thing, it's really great but I think they need to change that restriction. For me, it's a total bummer

Comment: The concept of a project is different in Android Studio vs. Eclipse. In Android Studio, a project can have many modules. Each module is the equivalent of an Eclipse project.